# How to add space in vscode emmet key suggestions?

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

There is inbuilt emmet suggestion of `@media` like in the image below and I wanted to add my custom snippets for `max-width` and `min-width`. Which I successfully did with below codes.

[image]

```
{
    "css": {
        "snippets": {
            "@mediaMaxWidth": "@media(max-width: ${1:768}px) {\n\t${2}\n}",
            "@mediaMinWidth": "@media(min-width: ${1:768}px) {\n\t${2}\n}"
        }
    }
}
```

**Problem:** :  Like in inbuilt emmet there is space between `@media screen`  , I want to create same for my custom one to looks like it so it become  `@media max-width` and `@media min-width` which I can't seems to achieve.

**What I tried and what I expected it to work:**

```
{
    "css": {
        "snippets": {
            "@media max-width": "@media(max-width: ${1:768}px) {\n\t${2}\n}",
            "@media min-width": "@media(min-width: ${1:768}px) {\n\t${2}\n}"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is the default snippet: https://github.com/emmetio/snippets/blob/master/css.json

Comment: @Alex I know, but looking at it doesn't give any clue :S

Comment: Did you just try creating your snippet in the snippets/css.json file?  It shows like you want it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There’s no way to add space in abbreviation shortcut. What you see in screenshot is a preview of expanded result, not actual snippet

Comment: So you also mean it won't show preview of expanded result for custom snippet. The custom snippet i wrote is almost exactly same as inbuilt actual snippet?  Is there to force it to show preview? Do we have any control on preview ?  Thanks

Comment: In new Emmet concept, abbreviation is expanded as autocomplete. The first autocomplete entry is expanded abbreviation, all the rest are shortcuts to insert into abbreviation. You can try typing `link` in HTML file: the first entry will replace shortcut with expanded result, next entries simply insert shortcut so you can add attributes to it as expand later

Comment: In most cases, you should Ctrl-Space for force autocomplete popup but implementation may differ for VS Code (plugin is developed by VS Code, not me)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

As @Mark had mentioned in the comment, we can put snippets in snippets/css.json   (less.json) if you use less.  **BUT** snippet structure looks different.

To add snippets open ***File > Preferences > User Snippets***  then choose the language you want to add snippets to, in this case i choose css.

Add codes based on the documentation in the file it self. Based on my requirement codes look like this.

```
    "media min width 768px": {
        "prefix": "@media min-width",
        "body": [
            "@media(min-width: ${1:768}px) {\n\t${2}\n}",
            "$3"
        ],
        "description": "Media min width"
    },

    "media max width 768px": {
        "prefix": "@media max-width",
        "body": [
            "@media(max-width: ${1:768}px) {\n\t${2}\n}",
            "$3"
        ],
        "description": "Media max width"
    }
```

[image]

**Result:**

[image]